# Using gravity to beat event horizon of black hole

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime, event-horizon

So I know it's impossible for an object A to escape a black hole once it has crossed the event horizon, but what if it had help from the outside? Is it theoretically possible for a massive enough object B to be maneuvered into place that would change the gravitational field enough that object A is no longer inside the event horizon and could escape?

Answer (score 0):

No? Why would you think a massive object would move the event horizon away? That simply extends the event horizon out further. For example, if you were to bring a second black hole close to the first, the two event horizons would bulge towards each other, not away, eventually connecting to form a bridged horizon before soon after combining into a single horizon.

Just thinking classically, an object will be attracted to the barycenter of two massive objects. To put the barycenter of a black hole just outside its event horizon, such that an object falling into that black hole instead falls towards this barycenter and remaining outside the event horizon, you would need an object on the order of the mass of the black hole, which will mean that second object will have its own event horizon that will end up just including the barycenter anyway.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. I thought that it would be somehow possible for an object to in some sense "run the gauntlet" between the two black holes, but it would be caught in between, even if by some fluke it fell to the barycenter and not either singularity.